# Can I run a server in a VM and then make requests to it in the host OS?

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm developing a web application in Ubuntu run in VM Ware Player. The VM is hosted on my Windows 8.1 machine. I want to test the application in Internet Explorer, so is there any way I can make requests to the server and test the application from the host OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to check the ip address of your VM

type this in ubuntu terminal:

```
ifconfig
```

check what ip address it uses then you can access it through browser

Comment: It spit back a lot of stuff. Anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: yes IP Address, eht0:10.1.1.1 or something like that

Comment: I don't think it's working. I've tried all the ones that look like an IP address or are next to a label that makes it sound like one.

Comment: Can you post output on pastebin or something so I can check what out put you get?

Comment: OK so your IP Address: 192.168.91.173 type that in your browser or whatever service you are running. thx

Comment: Yeah I tried that one, it didn't work. Inside Ubuntu, I'd use this ip:port to access the application:

http://0.0.0.0:9393

Do I need to incorporate that somehow?

Comment: ok so try this: 192.168.91.173:9393 if that does not work that means you need to bind your application that runs on Ubuntu box on that IP